# calloc in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do I transform the following ObjectiveC statements into SWIFT:

```
UInt32 *pixels;
pixels = (UInt32 *) calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32));
```

I tried to do the following:

```
var pixels: UInt32
pixels = (UInt32)calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32))
```

and I receive the error message:

> Int is not convertible to UInt

and the (UInt32) Casting didn't work as well.
Can someone give me some advice please? I am struggling a little bit with SWIFT still. Thank you.

Comment: How does any of that relate to Core Graphics?  You are simply allocating memory?  I'm no swift expert, but the first block of code is allocating a pointer to `UInt32` where the next block is just a `UInt32`.  What happens if you say `var pixels: UInt32*`??

Comment: Just instantiate an array of UInt32 and keep a reference. There's no need to `calloc`.

Comment: You really need to download the Swift books, especially the one about using Swift and Objective-C or C. You have no chance without them. The code that you are writing shows you need to learn the very basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easier way of allocating that array in swift:

```
var pixels = [UInt32](count: height * width, repeatedValue: 0)
```

If that's what you actually want to do.

But, if you need a pointer from calloc for some reason, go with:

```
let pixels = calloc(UInt(height * width), UInt(sizeof(UInt32)))
```

The type of `pixels` though must be a type of `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`, and you would handle it like a swift pointer in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift-3 :** 
**UnsafeMutablePointer is replace by UnsafeMutableRawPointer**

```
 var pixels = UnsafeMutableRawPointer( calloc(height * width, MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size) )
```

[image]

[Reference](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** know what you are doing and insist in allocating memory unsafely using `calloc`:

```
var pixels: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>
pixels = calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32))
```

or just

```
var pixels = calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32))
```