# convert UnsafeMutableRawPointer to swift3

Tags: swift2, swift3

I have this code in swift2

```
  private var RecordedDurationContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.alloc(1)
```

How convert into swift3

Comment: `public static func allocate(bytes size: Int, alignedTo: Int) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744536/calloc-in-swift/41221309#41221309

Answer (score 0):

```
private var RecordedDurationContext = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.alloc(1)

let a = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
a.pointee = 42

print("a's value: \(a.pointee)") // 42 

a.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.